# PowerApps - Export data from SharePoint list to Excel (issue with column order)

Tags: excel, list, sharepoint, powerapps

I'm making a PowerApps app, and I have a list of devices. The issue I have is that when I'm exporting my devices list into a CSV file, the columns aren't in the correct order. The list is originally a SharePoint list. What I did to export that into a CSV file works fine. The order of the columns is the only issue I have.
Here's the SharePoint list:
[image: share point list]
Here's the flux I made to export the list into CSV file (it's in french, sorry)
[image: my flux]
And finally, here's the CSV result file, as you can see, the columns aren't in the same order as the SharePoint list...
[image: the result CSV file]
Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me!

Comment: What did you try to resolve the issue?

Comment: I tried, in Powerapps, to change the order of the columns but it seems to be random when exporting... I don't know what to try else

Comment: I really need help on this please... UP !

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my question by myself. All I had to do was to go in my Flux, in the "Créer un tableau CSV" ("Create a CSV table" in english) and access the advanced options. After that, I needed to set the headers to "personalized" instead of "automatic", and attribute each personalized header name to the corresponding output from the previous action.